# Conjecture about odd primes

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics, totient-function, conjectures

For each odd prime $p$ there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$p\equiv n^2 \text{ (mod }\varphi(n^2))$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function.

I'm developing my Forth based computational system [Zet](http://forthmath.blogspot.se) to be used for testing conjectures and it seems that it generate conjectures as well...

What I have tried is to test the modular condition for squares of all integers less than $n$. All odd primes less than $n$ are represented then. It's not so that all odd number is represented - which seems to be the case if dropping the squaring: $p\equiv n \text{ (mod }\varphi(n))$ - instead the most of the numbers represented are primes.

Comment: Take $ n = p $, and note that $ \varphi(p^2) = p^2 - p $.

Comment: It's also true for $n=1$.  This is a trivial solution but I imagine you need to be very precise with computational systems, and $n=1$ precisely satisfies the statement as written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conjecture is (trivially) true, because we have $ \varphi(p^2) = p^2 - p $ for $ p $ prime, so that we have $ p \equiv p^2 \pmod{\varphi(p^2)} $. Thus, we may simply take $ n = p $ for any prime number.